# Code Insight for include files is not working

Tags: c++builder, code-completion, c++builder-10.1-berlin

CodeInsight / Auto-Completion in C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin doesn't work for include files. Is it supposed to work for includes? If so, what am I doing wrong?

I have CodeInsight activated in the options, but it shows me no list, even if I manually press <kbd>CTRL+SPACE</kbd>.

In the past, I've programmed with Visual Studio, where auto-completion works for includes. I really miss that feature.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Other IDEs, like Eclipse, also have auto-completion for includes. I've never seen it in C++Builder, but then I've never looked for it, either. CodeInsight/Auto-Completion has always been slow/buggy in C++Builder (works good in Delphi) so a lot of people tend to just turn it off.

Comment: @RemyLebeau is correct. The CodeInsight in C++ Builder has never worked correctly and to make the matter worst, it works differently depending on What **target platform** you have activated or whether or not you are using **classic compiler** (if targeting Win32) in your project option. I love C++ Builder and it is my main compiler/IDE, and as much as I love to have the CodeInsight working, I am forced to turn it off because not only it is slow and does not show the correct options, sometimes it causes the IDE to crash.